# Textbox/TextEntry num console application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, console

É possível adicionar uma *Textbox* a uma console *application*?

Comment: Poderia postar um exemplo de um código para que facilite te dar uma resposta?

Comment: Ué, será que precisa de mais informações para a pergunta ficar clara? Alguém percebe algo que falta nela? Pode informar?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Não. E não tem sentido fazer isto. Se quer ter estes controles precisa criar uma aplicação Windows Forms ou outro tipo que tenha isto. Se quiser abrir um console dentro desta aplicação, fique à vontade. Isto é possível. Não fica perfeito mas é o que dá para fazer.

A não ser que você esteja falando de criar um `TextBox` como console mesmo, fazendo semelhante ao que se encontra no WinForms mas em texto. Aí é possível mas terá que criar o controle manualmente. O console do .Net não dá muitas facilidades para fazer isto.